# Does linear independence imply algebraic independence for partitioned homogeneous polynomials?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, linear-independence

Define a partitioned homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ to be a polynomial in $$\mathbb Z[x_{11},\dots,x_{1n},\dots,x_{d1},\dots,x_{dn}]$$ with monomials from entries in (polynomials that are $d$-linear forms of a particular structure) vector $$(x_{11},\dots,x_{1n})\otimes\dots\otimes(x_{d1},\dots,x_{dn}).$$

1. Supposing if $f,g$ are two such polynomials with coefficient vectors linearly independent then when does it hold that they are algebraically independent?
2. Will it work if $\mathbb Z$ is replaced by another commutative ring?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your notation - do you mean that the polynomial is a linear combination of monomials of the form $x_{1a_1}x_{2a_2}\dots x_{da_d}$ with $1\leq a_k\leq n$?

Comment: @Wojowu Yes that is correct.

Comment: In other words, it is a $d$-linear form on $\mathbb{Z}^n$, right?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Yes that is correct.

Comment: Well, any $d$-linear form is a linear combination of forms of the shape given in Wojowu's comment.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I am asking if linear implies algebraic independence is easily seen?

Comment: Oh, this I don't know.